# Change diary location?

Tags: calendar, diary

The diary file is located by default at `~/diary`. I'd rather it wasn't. I've looked quite a bit through the reference over the past couple of days, I haven't seen anything generated in the .emacs that sets it, and there are no SX questions about it.

Does anyone know how to put your diary in a different directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To learn more about the variable `diary-file`, type `M-x describe-variable RET diary-file RET`  This can be set through the built-in customize interface -- `M-x customize-variable RET diary-file RET` -- or by placing something like the following snippet in the `.emacs` file:

```
(setq diary-file "/hello/world/diary-file")
```

If setting it manually, then restart Emacs or evaluate the expression.